# ASP.NET без Roslyn

Tags: asp.net

Подскажите пожалуйста, как удалить из проекта ASP.NET Web Forms  компоненты CodeDomProviders и Roslyn ?

Answer (score 1):

Решение - деинсталлировал пакеты NuGet, пересобрал проект.